# how to disable submit button after being used 1 time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What I am trying to do is the following.

A **user.rb** can **answer.rb** several **application.rb**'s created by a **company.rb**. However the user can only answer once per unique application.

I've already disabled this in the model but can't figure out how to do it in the view.

My answer controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

 def show
  @application = Application.find(params[:id])
  @answer = Answer.new
end 


def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params.merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
if @answer.save
  flash[:notice] = "You've successfully applied"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  flash[:alert] = "You've already applied"
  redirect_to root_url
end
end

private

 def answer_params
   params.require(:answer).permit(:answer_1, :answer_2, :answer_3, :application_id)
   end
 end
```

in the answer model I have a user_id that is stored.
Now my thinking is that we look at the current answer :id and check if current_user.id is present in it, if so we disable the button. But I haven't been able to do anything that turned out successfully.

The show.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @answer do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :application_id, value: @application.id %>

     <p>Question 1: <%= @application.question_1 %></p>
     <%= f.text_area :answer_1 %>

    .......

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

 <% end %>
```

Comment: check if the `answer` has a `user_id`, if so, it's been answered and show the appropriate message?

Comment: I don't know how to put that into programming though. Even though I know the action.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your app structure but from what I see, each answer has a `user_id`? If so, to check it you would do something like `<% if @answer.user_id.nil? # show submit button / do form logic else # show disabled message end %>`. The comment won't allow newlines so you'll need to add those yourself to try it.

Comment: @martincarlin87 I tried that and: 
<% if f.current_user.id.nil? %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% else %>
  <p>potato</p>
<% end %> 

but get undefined method `current_user' for some reason

Comment: You should put your form to another partial. Show action is only for show. Create actions "new" and 'edit', appropriate partials to make it working. Also, please refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html (CRUD section). In the end I believe you should have something like current_user.answered?(current_application) and then you can use it in your views to show/hide or enable/disable your buttons.

Comment: @user2755537 the `user_id` belongs to the `answer` does it not, so you'd have to use that and not `f`. Might worth updating your `answer` model to define the relationship as `:belongs_to => user` aswell.

Comment: I have belongs_to user. I now moved it to #new. Now still have the problem to see if the current_user.id has already answered this post and thus disable it.

Answer (score 0):

If use of jQuery is possible in Ruby, [you can use the .one() method](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
.one( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )                [jQuery 1.7+]

events
    Type: String
    One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" 
    or "keydown.myPlugin".
selector
    Type: String
    A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger
    the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when
    it reaches the selected element.
data
    Type: Anything
    Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered.
handler
Type: Function( Event eventObject )
    A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value false is also allowed as 
    a shorthand for a function that simply does return false.
```

Comment: The OP might need to hide the submit button on the first submission but I think the question is more to do with how to handle further visits to the same page and check if it's already been submitted by a user.